# Compare 2 columns in two different work sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What formula do i need to write to compare Column A in worksheet 1, and Column A in worksheet 2?

I just need to find a formula that tells me where Column A Worksheet 1 matches Column A in worksheet 2.

Note, Worksheet 2 might have a thousand rows.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by Column matches Column? I'm only guessing here, but are you trying to determine if a cell value in Worksheet 1 matches any cell in Worksheet 2?

Comment: yes exactly... so I'm trying to see if any values in column A of worksheet 1 are present in Column A of worksheet 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this in the same workbook (ie, one file with two sheets). Assuming that is what you mean by 2 different worksheets.

You can use either a vlookup to return the value (would return N/A if not found), or, slightly enhance it a bit to return a true/false. Here's the latter method.

On sheet1, cell B2, input this formula:

```
    =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)), "FALSE", "TRUE")
```

If the value is found anywhere in column A on sheet2, then it will return a TRUE response. You can change that "true" and "false" to anything you want such as 1 and 0. Drag the formula down as far as needed.

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: @charliebukowski If that works and meets your needs, then please consider approving the answer so that others will know it's resolved.

Comment: How do i approve the answer

Comment: There should be a checkmark to the left of the answer.